# Restrict array's value in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want my placement prop can have any string inside array but I want to restrict it to have only four values. I have created an enum though it would work it seems a wrong way. How can we achieve this in typescript?

```
export enum Placement {
  RIGHT = 'right',
  LEFT = 'left',
  TOP = 'top',
  bottom = 'bottom'
}

interface IProps {
  className?: string;
  placement: string[]; // Placement []
}
```

Comment: `placement: Placement[];` work as expected (by me). What doesn't work for you? The drawback is that you cannot put strings into it, just values of the `Placement` enum (i.e. instead of `['left', 'top']` you have to use `[Placement.LEFT, Placement.TOP]`. It is transpiled as `['left', 'top']` in the JavaScript code generated during compilation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want strings and not and enum, you can use a union type:

```
type Placement = 'right' | 'left' | 'top' | 'bottom';

interface IProps {
  className?: string;
  placement: Placement[]; // Placement []
}

const props: IProps = {
  className: 'X',
  placement: ['right', 'left', /*error*/ 'inbetween'],
};
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=11&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACgNgQwMYQLYQHbCgXigcgCcBLAcwAth8oAfAuCAMytoOAHsxq78Ajd4B1T4A3AFgAUJOJYIhRsmgBJGIU4BnKAG9JUKEkTr1AOQToA-AC4o64CQylxEvWEQp0Wa-EUfgAbQBdESgAehDYNzRMbEDJAF9JSSR2DFsoMDUwdWsVTM08HWd9QxMzCGt8AA18ABpddMjfaz8iMkpa+iYqGtCAKjk1Ql7w-BleCGAAdwhMfAC6iTiRIA)

Answer (score 1):

It works as expected

```
const placement:Placement[] = [Placement.RIGHT, Placement.LEFT]
```